# Rerender custom tab bar in react-navigtion

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Woking with react-navigation v5. Made custom tab bar from docs example. I put in ads banner inside the bottom tab bar. Now I want after purchase event to remove ads banner. But I am not sure how to do it. How to remove my banner right after purchase event?

This my custom tab bar code:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code on the answer using the Stackoverflow code tool.

Comment: if it will allow me post that much code i would use it

Answer (score -1):

I really dont read your code entirely so i dont know wich part is the ads part. But you can use a `conditional rendering` to decide when render or not your ads component. Something like this:

```
render(){
  return(
    <View>
    {this.state.ads && // <-- Start of the conditional part
     <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>ads here</Text>
    } // <-- End of the conditional part
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: this is rerender of component screen and i need to render in navigation bottom tab bar

Comment: yup, but this is justa an example, so you can use the conditional part on the part of your code that you need to. I cant copy your code so i cant provide you a example of how exactly you can make it work.

Comment: The problem is that i know how to add conditional rendering but I don't know how do I make rerender actually right after some event happens. Basically I need to render somehow my custom tab bar with bottom buttons/tabs and my ads banner after in-app purchase.